# Android_Alert Message_Which will not Close

Tags: android

I am trying to develop popup message box which shows warning to user and won't allow to go anywhere (even not allowed to go at home screen/menu).

I'm trying to put button on it until I press on that button and write username and password, so that user can't go any where.

Should I interrupt or simply call to another activity? As I want to do this above thing after completing task on 1st activity, And I want do above pop thing on next ativity.

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method for creating that popup like :

```
public void showAlert() {

        /* Layout that is shown inside the alert */
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        //create a layout that is shown inside ur popup and give its name over here
        final View calibrateView = factory.inflate(your layout, null);

        EditText username = (EditText)calibrateView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText password = (EditText)calibrateView.findViewById(R.id.password);

        /* Creating the popup */
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alert.setView(calibrateView);
        alert.setTitle(your title);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                //check whether username and password is present over here.
                //if present give ur intent code for moving to the next activity
                //if absent, then create an alert showing the error msg
            }
         });

        alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {            
            /* called when AlertDialog "Cancel" button is pressed.  */
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }
        });

        alert.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```